# How can I get a list of PDF files stored in android?

Tags: android, cordova

How can I get a list of PDF files stored in internal as well as external storage of an Android device in Cordova? I tried the File plugin but I'm unable to get a list of files.

Here's the code I tried, but it's only showing directories, not the files within:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() { 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,
        function (fileSystem) {
            var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(
                function (entries) {
                    //if(entries)
                    console.log(entries);
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: It would be good to show your attempt with the File plugin and the resulting data/message that failed.

Comment: @TylerH I edited the question, have a look at it. The Plugin is only showing a list of directories.